# Getting specific number of pedestrians inside pedWait

Tags: anylogic

I am very new to AnyLogic, and I just learned the basic Pedestrian process blocks. The problem I have right now is pulling out a specific number of pedestrians currently inside a pedWait rectangular node when a certain condition is met from a function that is called on begin wait of pedWait.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to being an AnyLogic user! For any questions like this one, you should consult the AnyLogic documentation. 

https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/pedestrian-library/pedwait.html

The function you want is pedWait.size().

Comment: Thank you for the response @Shingston however, pedWait.size() is not what I want. I want to get a number of people currently inside a pedWait block using the free() function. I am having problems doing that because I do not know the right syntaxes.